# Enable/disable app notification channel via shell (Android)

Tags: android, shell, settings, android-notifications

I'd like to toggle notification channel (not notification access) for some apps in script/command. After searching system files i found file /data/system/notification_policy.xml where this settings is stored.
File looks like

````
<channel id="ongoing_channel" name="Ongoing" desc="Low priority foreground service notifications" importance="0" sound="content://settings/system/notification_sound" usage="5" content_type="4" flags="0" locked="4" fgservice="true" />
<channel id="misc" name="Misc" desc="Miscellaneous" importance="3" sound="content://settings/system/notification_sound" usage="5" content_type="4" flags="0" show_badge="true" />
</package> ```

Tried to change value in file and after reboot it works, but command solution.
````